# Advice Making Other issue with Components

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class LogParamAdvice {
    
    @AfterThrowing(
           value= "execution(* com.demo..*(..)) && " +
            "!within(is(EnumType)) && " +
            "!within(is(FinalType))"
            ,throwing = "error")
    public void logErrorParam(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) throws Throwable {
        logErrorParams(joinPoint, error);
    }
    
    public void logErrorParams(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) throws Throwable {
        
        Gson gson =  new Gson();
        
        Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
        String mehodName = signature.getName();
        Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();
        
        MethodSignature method = (MethodSignature)joinPoint.getSignature();
        String[] parameters = method.getParameterNames();
        String classsName = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName();
        
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if(parameters.length > 0) {
            int index = 0;
            for(String parameter : parameters) {
                Object argumentValue = arguments[index];
                String stringyfiedValue = gson.toJson(argumentValue);
                
                builder.append( "name:"+parameter+" value:"+stringyfiedValue);
                index++;
            }
            log.error("Class: "+classsName+" Method: "+mehodName+" params:"+builder.toString()+" Exception Type: "+error.getClass()+" Message : "+error.getMessage());
            throw error;
        }else {
            log.error("Class: "+classsName+" Method: "+mehodName+"Exception Type: "+error.getClass()+" Message : "+error.getMessage());
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

this advice is making issue injecting other components.
it is not making any issue for @Service it is only making said issue in @Component

ie: service where the class doesn't implement any interface
how i came to know this is the culprit: after disabling the Advice it started working

Comment: please add at least 1 component and 1 service ...

Comment: sorry I actually dont understand your problem at all, is there any exception? Please show which classes are actually failing for you...and describe your problem in detail.  Thank you!

Comment: it is not injecting the components those are not  implementing any  INTERFACE

on runtime when i look for the specific bean it is throwing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException